# allow users to make changes to database tables in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, database, phpmyadmin

I am a beginner in programming and this is what i am trying to make: I am making a web application with questions and answers of certain problems. I have a login screen where you have to put in a specific code to access the website. If code is not entered, it wont let you access. There is also another code you can put in. That code will let you access another page where the user can edit the questions and answers. My Question is: Is there any way can you allow users to edit your database tables via a web application?

The only thing i have in that page are 2 buttons which say: (change table) or (add/delete table)

```
<div id="container">

    <div class="button1">
        <form action="" method="get">
            <input type="button" name="submit" value="Add/Delete table"/>
        </form>
    </div>


    <div class="button2">
        <form action="" method="get">
            <input type="button" name="submit" value="Change table"/>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

of course you can, for each table you want to edit (questions and answers here I guess) you will need :

1. [A controller](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers)
2. [A model](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#generating-model-classes)
3. [A request](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests)
4. [Authorizations](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization)

This is the minimum, you can add any customization then.

Reading the doc is a good starting point, it's very well written https://laravel.com/docs/9.x